# Audio duration not retrieved by a plugin "audioplayers" in flutter

Tags: php, amazon-s3, audio

I'm creating an app using flutter where I'm retrieving audios from the AWS-s3 bucket. Before I retrieve the audio I check if the user has access to that file. Then I add the audio to the plugin "audioplayers" and the audio is played without problems but the duration of the audio is never loaded.

The problem with the duration is happening just with iPhone, using flutter, chrome and safari.

This is my PHP code to retrieve the audio, I have not added the permissions check because if I remove that part of the code the result is the same. I think the problem is in how I retrieve the audio file:

```
function printAudio($audioID)
{
    $url = "my_file_url";
    header_remove();
    print_headers($url);
    //header("Content-Length: " . filesize($url));
    readfile($url);
}
function print_headers($url)
{
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    if ($headers != null) {
        foreach ($headers as $header) {
            print_if_needed($header);
            //header($header);
        }
    }
}

function print_if_needed($header)
{
    if (str_contains($header, "Accept-Ranges:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "Content-Length:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        $fileSize = (int)str_replace("Content-Length: ", "", $header);
        $rangeTo = $fileSize - 1;
        header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$rangeTo/$fileSize");
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "Content-Range:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "Content-Type:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "ETag:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "Last-Modified:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
}
```

I have added the content-range to check if that could solve the problem and the result is the same. As well I have tried using capitalized headers and lowercased.

I have tried retrieving the object using the AWS/s3 PHP API and the result is always the same, the audio can be played but the duration of the audio is never retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code using this code [github/pomle](https://github.com/pomle/php-serveFilePartial)

It looks like I need to add extra code for audio range when you move the position in the audio.

```
function print_if_needed($header){
    if (str_contains($header, "Content-Length:")) {
        $byteOffset = 0;
        $fileSize = (int)str_replace("Content-Length: ", "", $header);
        $byteLength = $fileSize;

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && preg_match('%bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?%i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $match)) {
            ### Offset signifies where we should begin to read the file
            $byteOffset = (int)$match[1];
            ### Length is for how long we should read the file according to the browser, and can never go beyond the file size
            if (isset($match[2])) {
                $finishBytes = (int)$match[2];
                $byteLength = $finishBytes + 1;
            } else {
                $finishBytes = $fileSize - 1;
            }
            $cr_header = sprintf('Content-Range: bytes %d-%d/%d', $byteOffset, $finishBytes, $fileSize); 
            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content");
            header($cr_header);  ### Decrease by 1 on byte-length since this definition is zero-based index of bytes being sent
            $byteRange = $byteLength - $byteOffset;
            header(sprintf('Content-Length: %d', $byteRange));
        }
        else{
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            header($header);
            $rangeTo = $fileSize - 1;
            header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$rangeTo/$fileSize");
            $byteRange = $byteLength - $byteOffset;
            header(sprintf('Content-Length: %d', $fileSize));
        }
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "Content-Type:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "ETag:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
    if (str_contains($header, "Last-Modified:")) {
        header(strtolower($header));
        return;
    }
}
    
function printAudio($audioID){
    $url = "my_file_url";
    header_remove();
 //I HAVE MOVED THESE HEADERS HERE FOR CODE VISIBILITY, IT IS NOT NEEDED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM.
    header_remove('Cache-Control');
    header_remove('Pragma');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes', true);
    header(sprintf('Expires: %s', date('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 90) . ' GMT'));
    print_headers($url);
    readfile($url);
}
```

I needed to control when the audio used a range. When I fixed that, it stopped in android, I had to add the else to add the headers when there is no range in the audio.

Comment: I have to check this code, it is returning every single time the same range of audio